# Why is the Pythagorean Theorem not the Pythagorean Law?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Why do we call the Pythagorean Theorem a theorem, not a law?

As far as I know, we call a theorem a theorem because though it's reliable in every observable case, its truthfulness cannot be proven for *every* case. However I've looked and it seems as though we (as the human race) have *very* extensive proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem, considering every case. Why is it that it hasn't made the transition from theorem to law? Is my terminology confused? Is it not as proven as I think it is? Is there some other condition for being a law that I don't know about?

Comment: If a theorem is proven, then it is proven for every possible case satisfying the hypothesis of the theorem. That's the whole point

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem

Comment: It sounds to me like you got the uses of "theorem" and "law" mixed up

Comment: I think the OP is mixed between the uses of "theorem" in Mathematics and "law" in Science. A theorem is a statement that can be proved through logic alone. Theorems do not generally rely on real-world evidence. A scientific law is a statement that summarizes a conclusion obtained from a large body of real-world evidence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law). This is largely why I caution people grouping Math together with the other Natural/Physical sciences. You'll rarely ever see a Mathematician performing an experiment

Comment: I think the confusion is between "theorem" and "theory". I have never come across the word "theorem" used in the natural sciences in the way the OP suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have jumbled mathematical and scientific terminology. Theorems state what is mathematically proven. Various kinds of scientific conclusions, including laws, are well-evidenced (with the whole of the philosophy of science as a footnote to that).